The vagrant-libvirt plugin is failing to install on Sonoma 14.6.1. Is this an M1 Mac Silicon limitation?
Here's the error message:
vagrant plugin install vagrant-libvirt
Installing the 'vagrant-libvirt' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
/opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2245:in `raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate fog-core-2.6.0, because excon-0.112.0 conflicts with excon (~> 1.0) (Gem::ConflictError)
    from 

Trying to resolve the gem conflict.


Please could you edit your question and reformat it? As it stands it is difficult to read.

As the error indicates there is a gem conflict. fog-core-2.6.0 relies on excon ~> 1.0 but something else you have installed relies on excon-0.112. We cannot resolve this for you based solely on this post but I can say definitively it has nothing to do with you OS or the chip

I can reproduce this on ubuntu. So it's not a mac issue :\

I've solved it by changing the fog-core dependency on the source, building the gem file and installing the plugin from it. Here's how to do it:
https://github.com/vagrant-libvirt/vagrant-libvirt/issues/1830#issuecomment-2447925186
Quoting the comment:

What I did was cloning the repository and changing
s.add_runtime_dependency 'fog-core', '~> 2'

to
s.add_runtime_dependency 'fog-core', '~> 2.5.0'

inside the
vagrant-libvirt.gemspec file
Then rebuild the plugin (using gem build) and installing it with
VAGRANT_DISABLE_STRICT_DEPENDENCY_ENFORCEMENT=1 vagrant plugin install ./vagrant-libvirt-0.12.3.pre.18.gem from inside the
repository directory.


where is the file that you changed?

I don't see the file under /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/specifications

This appears to be an inconsistency between fog-core and vagrant_cloud. vagrant_cloud 3.1.1 relies on excon ~> 0.73 which resolves to excon-0.112.0 but fog-core 2.6 relies on excon ~>1.0. It appears that vagrant_cloud has addressed this in their main branch but has not released yet. This change was only made 3 days ago (Commit). In viewing the change log you can see 3.1.2 is unreleased but it appears their is imminent intent, at which point the issue will be resolved.

It's in the source of the repo that I linked. Clone the repo, change the file, build it locally and install from the built gem file

Sorry, I'm kind of new to a lot of this.  I did a git clone, modified the file.  How do I "build" it?  I know how to gem install.

I did a git clone, git add vagrant-libvirt.gemspec, git commit -m "message".  Not sure if I used the right message.  Then a "gem install fog-core".  Seems like i did it correctly, no errors.  But it still bombs out on me.   Same error message./opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2245:in `raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate fog-core-2.6.0, because excon-0.112.0 conflicts with excon (~> 1.0) (Gem::ConflictError)

It's all in the answer: "rebuild the plugin (using gem build) and installing it with VAGRANT_DISABLE_STRICT_DEPENDENCY_ENFORCEMENT=1 vagrant plugin install ./vagrant-libvirt-0.12.3.pre.18.gem from inside the repository directory".
No git commands are mentioned (git is not for building software). The gem build command will generate the file vagrant-libvirt-0.12.3.pre.18.gem that you'll use for the second command.

Using the variable before the command: VAGRANT_DISABLE_STRICT_DEPENDENCY_ENFORCEMENT=1 is only needed if you're using vagrant version 2.4.2 (because this version has a bug on it's dependencies), if you're using a previous version you shouldn't need it and could just run vagrant plugin install ./vagrant-libvirt-0.12.3.pre.18.gem. Let me know if works out for you. Cheers

Installing the 'vagrant-libvirt-0.12.3.pre.20.gem' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
Vagrant failed to install the requested plugin because it depends
on development files for a library which is not currently installed
on this system. The following library is required by the 'vagrant-libvirt-0.12.3.pre.20.gem'
plugin:
libvirt
If a package manager is used on this system, please install the development
package for the library. The name of the package will be similar to:
libvirt-dev or libvirt-devel

I don't see how to install libvirt-devel or libvirt-dev using Brew.

https://github.com/vagrant-libvirt/vagrant-libvirt/issues/1713

I ran into these issues as well on debian and eventually using the source repositories has worked. But since you're on macOS I can't really help you anymore. Seems like there's a lot of problems running libvirt on apple silicon, you'll have to read through those issues to possibly find something that works. Good luck

Thanks.  Can't say we didn't try.  Waiting for the next version of Vagrant.

Could you mark the question as answered then since it answers your main question ? That should help other people looking for the same thing
